# 503 Service Unavailable...Trying to Read Configuration data from file

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-503

I tried to go to one of my local websites and encountered this error in the event log: "The worker process for application pool 'My Website' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code."

I received a 503 Service Unavailable on the website and the app pool is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to go to C:\inetpub\temp\appPools.  In my case, there was a shortcut with the name of my website that doesn't go anywhere.  I deleted the shortcut and restarted the website.  A folder with the name of the website is created with a .config file inside of it.  After that, the website works and the app pool continues running.

This was a strange error.  I hope this will help anyone else who encounters it.